# Unable to create data tables dynamically using TextField input

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, datatables, widget

I am trying out to create an invoice application, wherein the user is entering the data, and then it should come up listed as a table.

What I have achieved so far is just a single row with just a single user input detail like with errors in it as well...
I wanted the application to

[image: this]

HardCoded Code:

```
class Sixth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return SixthState();
  }
}

class SixthState extends State<Sixth> {
  final pdf = pw.Document();
  String path;
  share() async {
    Share.shareFiles([path]);
  }

  create() async {
    print('creating');
    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(12),
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return <pw.Widget>[
          pw.Paragraph(
              text: 'SOLUTION HUB\nVENDORS',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.Paragraph(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(left: 450),
              text: 'Billing Address:',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.Row(children: [
            pw.Paragraph(
                text: 'wrqijwqiojqwoirjq\nirjorwiuroeriuwor\noerweo8rw',
                padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 10)),
            pw.SizedBox(width: 370),
            pw.Paragraph(
                text: 'wrqijwqiojqwoirjq\nirjorwiuroeriuwor\noerweo8rw',
                padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 10))
          ]),
          pw.Paragraph(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              text: 'PAN No. ${panvalue}',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.Paragraph(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              text: 'GST Registration No. ${gstvalue}',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.Paragraph(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              text: 'Order No. ${ordernovalue}',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.Paragraph(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              text: 'Order Date. ${orderdatevalue}',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.Paragraph(
              padding: pw.EdgeInsets.only(left: 450),
              text: 'INVOICE NUMBER\n03950234982042980',
              style: pw.TextStyle(fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold)),
          pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
          pw.Table.fromTextArray(data: <List<String>>[
            <String>[
              'SI\nNo.',
              'Description',
              'Unit\nPrice',
              'Qty',
              'Net Amount',
              'Tax\nRate',
              'Tax\nType',
              'Tax\nAmt',
              'Total\nAmt'
            ],
            <String>[
              '1',
              '${SecondState.descriptionController.text}',
              '${ThirdState.unitpriceController.text}',
              '1',
              '500',
              '${FourthState.taxrateController.text}',
              '${FourthState.taxtypeController.text}',
              '${FourthState.taxamountController.text}',
              '276.6'
            ],
          ])
        ];
      },
    ));
  }

  Future save() async {
    print('sacing');
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String documentpath = directory.path;
    File file = File("$documentpath/example.pdf");
    setState(() {
      path = "$documentpath/example.pdf";
    });
    file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());
  }

  int _value = 1;
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<Offset> offset;
  static var panvalue;
  static var gstvalue;
  static var ordernovalue;
  static var orderdatevalue;
  static var descriptionvalue;
  static var unitpricevalue;
  static var quantityvalue;
  static var taxratevalue;
  static var taxtypevalue;
  static var taxamtvalue;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('ORDER DETAILS'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {}, //USER PROFILE
              icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
              iconSize: 30,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 220, top: 20),
              child: Text(
                'SOLUTION HUB \n VENDORS',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 240),
              child: Text(
                'Billing Adress:',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                  child:
                      Text('Ubga wjpw wiqjoiw\n owqkdw qwok qoqkw \nojq vpoqk'),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  child: Text('oefkwpfoke 20-32 \n 032902 0239 \n 0392230'),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              width: 800,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 10, top: 45),
              child: Text(
                "Pan No. ${panvalue}",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 800,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 10, top: 25),
              child: Text(
                "GST REGISTRATION NO. ${gstvalue}",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 800,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 10, top: 25),
              child: Text(
                "Order No. ${ordernovalue} ",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 400,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 20, top: 25),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Order Date: ${orderdatevalue}",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'INVOICE NUMBER',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 250, top: 5),
                child: Text('5920384283429')),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        child: DataTable(columnSpacing: 4, columns: [
                  DataColumn(
                      label: Text(
                    'Si\nNo.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  )),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Description')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Unit\nPrice')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Qty')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Net\namount')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Tax\nRate')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Tax\nType')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Tax\nAmt')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Total\nAmt'))
                ], rows: [
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(Wrap(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '1',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                    DataCell(Text(
                      '${SecondState.descriptionController.text}',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )),
                    DataCell(Wrap(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '${ThirdState.unitpriceController.text}',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                    DataCell(Text('${ThirdState.quantityController.text}')),
                    DataCell(Text('500')),
                    DataCell(Text('${FourthState.taxrateController.text}')),
                    DataCell(Text('${FourthState.taxtypeController.text}')),
                    DataCell(Text('${FourthState.taxamountController.text}')),
                    DataCell(Text('500')),
                  ])
                ]))),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
            ),
            ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 110,
              height: 50,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.blue[300],
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text("COMPLETE ACTION USING"),
                          content: Container(
                            height: 150,
                            width: 100,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    create();
                                    await save();
                                    share();
                                  },
                                  child: Text('WhatsApp'),
                                ),
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Text('Gmail'),
                                ),
                                FlatButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                  child: Text("Download"),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
                child: Text('Share'),
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

## What I want to achieve is [this](https://xd.adobe.com/view/28a94e92-fb99-4de5-881b-32c15df8d6fd-7dfa/screen/89425919-0853-45d1-adc1-7c6a2e95bb66/)

It should automatically add rows as user inputs enter details

Errors I have encountered:

1. Whenever I going to add more items the previous data are stored in the text fields.
2. There are more colors on the right side but am unable to view it.

Please help me solve this issue

Comment: @JideGuru Please check

Comment: Can you provide more details about MS-paint kind of features ?

Comment: Features like we can paint over the pdf document, highlight the text, and also change the colours

Comment: Check if [dart_pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package can help

Comment: No, it did not solve my issue

Comment: You might have to look at the source code of those packages, cannot think of easy way to implement the requirements you mentioned.

Comment: @JideGuru Please have a look